# What does true false actually do in php

Tags: php, function

I have seen many php function & many php scripts, I always find

```
function check() {
    if(isset($_POST['example'])){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What does this true & false do? does false stops the query from executing further?

Actually i have a login page where I want to stop the executing if user is not found in database like:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) !=1) {
    // if result is not 1 then executing must be stop here, hello should not be echo
}

echo "hello";
```

further down are more script that should be executed only when result is 1

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php 
-`for those of you who think that using return in a script is the same as using exit note that: using return just exits the execution of the current script, exit the whole execution.`

So i tried a code at my localhost

```
$a = 1;
if($a == 0){
echo "Its 0"; }
else{ return; }
echo "hi";
```

after wring return false the word hi was not executed & when i removed return false then the hi word was executed

Now i will tell you what i really want to know

```
 $query3 =mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
 if(mysqli_num_rows($query3) != 1)
   {
      $er1 = "Username doesn't exist"; 
    }
else{
$query4 ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result1=mysqli_query($connecDB, $query3);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) != 1)
   {
      $er1 = "Email doesn't exist"; 
   } else {
    // do this
    }
    }
```

Now you see above i have used if statement into else statement and more if statement into else which makes my php script very much complicated & very hard to understand

I just want to know what is the better way to execute script like shown below

```
$query3 =mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
     if(mysqli_num_rows($query3) != 1)
       {
          $er1 = "Username doesn't exist"; 
        }
    else{ // stop the execution here & just print this $er1 on the page without exit or die }
```

i want to stop the execution because of below example

```
 $a = 1;
if($a == 0){
echo "Its 0 "; }
else{ //if it's not 0 then it means user is not registered do not echo echo hi below }
echo "hi";
```

Now the hi is always executed

Comment: It's all in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: In your case later you can use if(check()) { then you have $_POST['example'] set and can execute some other script that needs this variable }. It is always better to use such functions if you are using DRY programming method

Comment: `exit` and `die()` will stop execution

Comment: true and false are just values. They don't do anything them selves. As in your first example it's returns true to indicate the function worked. For your second example it's not going to work how your comment says. To stop the program you need to put the exit(); in your if statement.

Comment: @BenSwinburne if i use exit & die the page will exit & blank page will be shown

Comment: Correct; that's not to say you can't output something else before exiting. Your comment says `executing must be stop here` which is what `exit/die()` will achieve. You could also put the `echo "hello";` in an else. Lots of ways to prevent hello echoing.

Comment: @BenSwinburne check the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes the `function` stop executing is the Control Structure `return`, `true` or `false` are  `Boolean` variables, also represented as `1` and `0` respectively.

---

```
if(function that returns a boolean !=1)
```

The `if` will only execute if `function that returns a boolean` is `true` (`1`)

---

Learn more about [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and [Boolean variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

---

Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: if i use exit & die the page will exit & blank page will be shown, what could be the best way? currently i'm using if(mysqli_num_rows($query) !=1) { } else{ echo "hi" }

Comment: what are you trying to do ? take your time to think well and update your question will as clear an concise as you can.